# SOAP webservice consume issue

Tags: java

I want to consume SOAP Web-Service in java 8 through JAXB.
Web service request contains Header and and body as seen below.
Request XML format:

```
<soap12:Header>
    <SoapHeaderData >
        <userName>string</userName>
        <Password>string</Password>
    </SoapHeaderData>
</soap12:Header>
<soap12:Body>
    <TestService >
        <TestServiceData>
            <name>string</name>
            <nameValid>boolean</nameValid>
        </TestServiceData>
    </TestService>
</soap12:Body>
```

Response XML format:

```
<soap12:Header>
    <SoapHeaderDataOut >
        <intResponseCode>int</intResponseCode>
        <strArMsg>string</strArMsg>
        <strEnMsg>string</strEnMsg>
    </SoapHeaderDataOut>
</soap12:Header>
<soap12:Body>
    <TestServiceResponse  >
        <TestServiceResult>
            <IsValid>boolean</IsValid>
        </TestServiceResult>
    </TestServiceResponse>
</soap12:Body>
```

Can someone help me, how to get the `<SoapHeaderDataOut>` tag data from the response.

Please also let me know if there are any other ways to call such a Web-Service using Java.

Comment: I am using below code : TestServicesSoap tService = new testServices().getTestServicesSoap(); Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
            headers.put("userName", Collections.singletonList("User"));
            headers.put("Password", Collections.singletonList(createSoapHeaderIn.getPassword()));
      req_ctx.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
            TestServicesRequest request = new TestServicesRequest();
        request.setName("DAS");
      TestServicesResponse tResponse = tService.testName(request);

Comment: First, you need to check if the wsdl is the right one. ¿how to do that? "localhost:8080/mySoapService?WSDL". Then, try to use something like SOAP UI or PostMan. Regards

Comment: @augusto It is working fine from SOAP UI.I want to consume using Java